# Laravel 5 - saving data stored in 2d array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a form which takes the following structure

```
<tr id='actionRow'>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name='actionInput[0][]' id="actionInput"  placeholder='Action' class="form-control"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="responsibility" name="actionInput[1][]" id="responsibilityInput">
            <option value=""></option>
            @foreach($users as $user)
                <option value="{{ $user->userName }}">{{ $user->userName }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name='actionInput[2][]' id="dateInput" placeholder='Completion Date' class="form-control dateControl"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have an option for the user to add rows to this form, and it basically clones the table row.  The end result I get in my controller when I output actionInput is something like the following

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Action Input 1"
    1 => "Action Input 2"
    2 => "Action Input 3"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Responsibility Input 1"
    1 => "Responsibility Input 2"
    2 => "Responsibility Input 3"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Date Input 1"
    1 => "Date Input 2"
    2 => "Date Input 3"
  ]
]
```

When this data is added to my database table, a table row should consist of one bit of data from each array.  So if I take the above data and insert it into a database, my table rows should look like the following

```
Action  |  Responsibility   | Date
-------------------------------------
Input 1 |  Responsibility 1 | Date 1
-------------------------------------
Input 2 |  Responsibility 2 | Date 2
-------------------------------------
Input 3 |  Responsibility 3 | Date 3
-------------------------------------
```

In my controller I am currently doing this

```
$actions = Input::get('actionInput');

foreach($actions as $action => $category) {
    $contactReportActions = new ContactReportActionsDoc();
    $contactReportActions->contactReportId = $contactReport->id;
    foreach($category as $key => $value){
        $contactReportActions->action = $value;
        $contactReportActions->responsibility = $value;
        $contactReportActions->deliveryDate = $value;
    }
    $contactReportActions->save();
}
```

The problem is, that produces something like the following

```
Action           |  Responsibility   | Date
----------------------------------------------------------
Input 1          |  Input 2          | Input 3
----------------------------------------------------------
Responsibility 1 |  Responsibility 2 | Responsibility 3
----------------------------------------------------------
Date 1           |  Date 2           | Date 3
----------------------------------------------------------
```

So how could I correct this within my controller so it inputs the data to my database correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
<tr id='actionRow'>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="actionInput[{{$key}}]['action']" id="actionInput"  placeholder='Action' class="form-control"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="responsibility" name="actionInput[{{$key}}]['responsibility']" id="responsibilityInput">
            <option value=""></option>
            @foreach($users as $user)
                <option value="{{ $user->userName }}">{{ $user->userName }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="actionInput[{{$key}}]['date_input']" id="dateInput" placeholder='Completion Date' class="form-control dateControl"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the view, you should generate a random or sequential key to the array, and store the table's columns with their names. For each row you clone later, you generate another key.

This layout will also allow a easier entity edit if you need to.

Then, in the Controller, you can separate each entity property like this:

```
    foreach (\Input::get('actionInput', array()) as $entityData)
    {
        $entity = ContactReportAction::find($entityData["id"]) ?: new ContactReportAction;
        $entity->fill($entityData);
        $entity->save();
    }
```

Check if this helps you...

Comment: Just a quick question - How could I generate the random key, and what is $class?

Comment: The $key is just a random or sequential key, what are you doing to clone the rows? Are you using javascript?

Comment: Yes, I am using javascript to clone.

Comment: You are already counting in your javascript in `i` variable. So, you can use it to create an attribute like `key`, and then use it to change the names of the inputs in the row you cloned with something like `$name = $name.replace('['+($key-1)+']', '['+$key+']');`

Comment: In the controller, what is $entityData["id"]?  It currently has no id so it complains about this variable

Comment: This line is just to avoid duplicated data when edit. If you won't edit anything, so you can use just: `$entity = new ContactReportAction;`